# Flutter: Can't run Android in release mode since AGP 8

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

My Flutter version is 3.16.7. It gets stuck on the splash screen. Since updating android to support AGP 8, I've been getting this error only in release mode, which I believe to be the cause:

`W/FlutterEngineCxnRegstry(12708): Attempted to register plugin (jb.a@f1844c0) but it was already registered with this FlutterEngine (mb.c@ec7f5f9).`

The plugin `jb.a@f1844c0` seems to be minified as it changes every time I run the app.